# Using the Discrete and Fast Fourier Transform for Polynomial Multiplication

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis

I need to multiply $ f(x) = x^2-3$ by $ g(x) = -2x$ using both Fourier transformations. I think I have found the roots of some equation, and it gives f(x) $$= 1,\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2} and \frac{-1-i\sqrt3}{2} $$.

g(x) is similarly

$$ = 1, -1 $$

Evaluating f at its points gives

$$ -2, \frac{-7-i\sqrt3}{2} and \frac{-7+i\sqrt3}{2}$$

and evaluating g at its points gives

$$-2,2$$

However, I have no idea where to go after this to calculate the polynomial multiplication of this.

Thanks for any help, as you can see I am really struggling with this.

Comment: What are you allowed to use for finding convolutions? What are you allowed to use for finding Fourier and Inverse Fourier Transforms? I can certainly add these calculations (and you did some if it correctly by hand, but are you allowed a computer for the DFT and inverse DFT parts?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Try using the convolution.